# After starting another Activity and inflating new Layout, Layout of MainActivity still visible

Tags: layout, overlapping

I want to use a Navigation Drawer within my App by using activities instead of fragments. By using Layout inflater in the different activities I tried to keep the same navigation drawer as in the MainActivity, but to change the inner layout. My problem is that somehow the layout of the MainActivity cant be replaced. When clicking on a item in the navigation drawer the new Activtiy opens and starts the layoutinflater. But the Layout Of the Main Activity remains, while the layout of the other Activity is just added.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
public static String TAG = "MainActivity";

DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Log.d(TAG, "CREATED");



NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, ^ 
toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_closed);
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.Mensa_in_der_Nähe:
                Intent anIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
    LocationActivity.class);
                startActivity(anIntent);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                break;

        }
        return false;
     }
    });
```

Then the xml file of main activity:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true">



 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/overview_coordinator_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/canteen_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/dish_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

   </FrameLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
 android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="start"
 android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:background="@android:color/white"
 app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
```

the other activity:

```
 public class LocationActivity extends MainActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 FrameLayout contentFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) 
 findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
 getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_location, 
 contentFrameLayout);
  }}
```

And the xml file of the other activity:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TimePicker
  android:id="@+id/timePicker"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```